# Java url-query html special characters (google)

Tags: java, url, translation, google-translate

I have a problem with my Java application. I have a big text, which sometimes include "*a*", "*br*" and "*p*" html-tags.

The text needs to be translated via Google Translate. And I'm **forced**(!) to make a translation-query to:

```
http://translate.google.com/m?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=" + tl + "&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q="+URLEncoder.encode(text);
```

Now my problem is with these pesky tags. First of all I replace all the links with their text analoges:

```
text.replaceAll("<a (.*) href=\"(.*)\">(.*)</a>", "$2");
```

My problem is: When I pass this text to the GT, it just removes all the links so I get no text-links back, only the rest of the text.

If I try to pass the text with **NON**-replaced links - if the link href is very long (like my links, because they are pretty long) it just crops it out entirely, so, for example,

> a
>   href="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASDADSADSADSADASAAAAAAAAASADDSADSADASDASDSA" will get transformed to plain "a" (with everything blank after it)

What should I do about it ? How to make it work properly, so that it wouldn't bother my links in the text ?

Thanks in advance!

P.S I have no other option to use any other API, query only!

Comment: HTTP GET is not able to support arbitrary long parameters. A POST is needed to submit a long text. You're using the wrong tool for the job I'm afraid.

Comment: The problem is not with GET itself. I can request a long-texts for translations, but the links in the text will get cropped. :(